# How to Send a Json file in Patch request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Need to send a Bulk Patch request to add team members. Using CSV, I will able  do it one at a time, so converted into JSON file and using "FileToString" method to read the same like this

```
"members": [${__FileToString(${_eval(${convertcsv_Patch})}.txt,,)}]
```

but getting below error -

```
{"error":{"code":422,"message":"message.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","errors":[{"scope":"error.scope","reason":"error.reason","message":"unknown token *\nNear:   \"members\": \r\n  [ *"}]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Description of [HTTP Status 422](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422) is

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 422 Unprocessable Entity response status code indicates that the server understands the content type of the request entity, and the syntax of the request entity is correct, but it was unable to process the contained instructions.
>
> **Important: The client should not repeat this request without
>   modification.**

That means the file is syntactically correct JSON file, but not what server is expecting.
What you should try:-

1. [Add View Result Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree)
2. Check request formed after reading the file and make appropriate changes to payload

Comment: The request body after executing the step is this - "members":  [ **ERR**  ]. What I think it implies is "something is wrong in reading the json/txt file"

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to say what's wrong without seeing:

1. Your `${convertcsv_Patch})}.txt` file
2. The value of the `${convertcsv_Patch}` variable in the [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
3. "Body data" tab of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler
4. Request payload (Request -> Request Body view of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener)
5. Contents of [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging)

Most probably your request is malformed, it should look like at least:

```
{"members":[${__FileToString(${_eval(${convertcsv_Patch})}.txt,,)}]}
```